# Specify Devise (or bcrypt) Token Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, devise, bcrypt

My users could have multiple keys and I'd like them to be distinguishable just by looking at them. I'd like to add a few characters before each token type (so I'd like to add `ses_` before each session token).

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using Devise (which I believe uses bcrypt?). I've read Devise's entire documentation but I cannot find where to override the tokens tokenisation.

Comment: Are you using TokenAuthenticatable or standard (database) Authenticatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least painful scenario I see is hooking lower into the warden, like in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/r00k/906356

In your case would look like:

```
# In config/initializers/local_override.rb:

require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class LocalOverride < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        # If token came as: "Authorization: SES blahblahhash"
        token.provided? && ("ses" == token.scheme ||
        # If token came as: "Authorization: SOMEOTHER blahblahhash"
        "someother" == token.scheme)
        # shorter: token.provided? && ["ses", "someother"].include? token.scheme
      end

      def token
        @token ||= Rack::Auth::AbstractRequest.new(env)
      end

      def authenticate!

          # assuming that you name columns in pattern : <scheme_name>_token
          # so ses_token and someother_token would be just regular columns
          # and you don't have to do any extra devise magic about them outside this strategy
          # token.params will be a string containing blahblahhash
          if user = User.where(token.scheme + "_token" => token.params).first
            success!(user)
          else
            fail
          end 
      end 
    end 
  end 
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:local_override, Devise::Strategies::LocalOverride)



# In config/initializers/devise.rb

config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :local_override
```

Comment: Doesn't that just look for "ses_" + token? What would the name of the attribute have to be in this case?

Comment: as you can see I assumed that there is a dedicated column for the token called something like `ses_token`

Comment: Where is that defined? Is it the `env['X-SES-TOKEN]`? Does that get converted into the `ses_token` column? From your example, I see from `User.find_by_ses_token(ses_token: "ses_" + token)`, you are just searching for `"ses_" + token`. But how do I actually set it in the database to be `"ses_" + token`? If I search for `ses_ + token`, that won't work because the token that is being generated and stored in the database does not have the `ses` token. Something else needs to be done to add `ses_` to new tokens. Right?

Comment: In trying to support multiple tokens, how would I designate multiple tokens names? Is that possible, or does Devise only take one token attribute per model? I saw a solution that uses Redis but I'm trying to keep all my three tokens in one model in the same database I don't understand how Warden strategies are called. If I have a TokenAuth strategy for one token, and then a custom strategy for the two other. How do I decide which strategy gets called according to which token was passed? I am passing tokens as HTTP Basic Auth. Wouldn't that all go to TokenAuthenticable?

Comment: Check the edits. I can't say for sure whether it is possible on the higher level, but I'm sure it's not any less work than doing it on warden level. And moreover you get a portable strategy that you'll be able to use without devise (which works only for rails so far).

Comment: Oh nice. So basically the token is stored raw without the prefix, but processing it on the outside with the appropriate prefix. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I proposed. Doing it the other way around will cost you more lookups and more complicated indexes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32340/discussion-between-forker-and-darksky)